Fundamental domain of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$
Serre, in the book A Course in Arithmetic, shows that $D=\{ z\in H;\ |z|\geq 1\ \wedge \ |Re(z)|\leq 1/2 \}$ is a fundamental domain for the action of $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ in the complex upper half plane. However, from what I understand (I may be wrong), he does not show that $D$ is a connected subset of the complex upper half plane, and all definitions of fundamental domain require this (Serre does not define fundamental domain). Did he really not show it, does he not need to show it, or is this fact obvious?

Draw $D$ and try to find a proof!

Not only it is connected, it is also convex from hyperbolic geometry viewpoint.

@psl2Z here is a try: Define a path $\gamma : [0,1]\to H$ such that $\gamma(0)=z_1$ and $\gamma(1)=z_2.$ We can take a path within $D$ that connects $z_1$ to $z_2$ by adjusting the imaginary part. Since this path can be chosen to remain entirely in $D$, we conclude that $D$ is path-connected, and then connected.

Yes. You can write an answer.
